# Using linq to check if list contains x and y together

Tags: vb.net, linq

[image]Say I have a list that contains values "x", "y" and "z". I want to check if it contains "x" or ("y" and "z").

I tried using the `Any` extension method but I don't think I m doing it right.

```
Dim retValue As Boolean = userRoles.Any(Function(a) (a.Name.ToLower() = "x") _ 
    OrElse (a.Name.ToLower() = "y" AndAlso a.Name.ToLower() = "z"))
```

Can someone suggest how it can be done?

Note: Added the roleList. It contains 3 values General.Alien, General.Employee and Internal.External.

Now i need to check if my list contains either (general.alien and internal.external) or general.employee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work as expected:

```
Dim containsXorelseYandZ As Boolean = userRoles.
    Any(Function(ur) "x".Equals(ur.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) _
    OrElse {"y", "z"}.All(Function(name) userRoles.
    Any(Function(ur) name.Equals(ur.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
```

So you need to look twice into the collection if it didn't contain "x". The second time it's using `Enumerable.All` on the `string()` which contains both names that must be contained.

Comment: How can `ur.Name` both be "z" AND a different value? Isn't that statement inherently false?

Comment: @Flater: you're right, oh dear! Then only the second approach makes sense.

Comment: I dont wanna check if my list contains letter, I need to check if roleList contains x role if not then check if it contains both y and z

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean if the list contains (separate) items X or Y, and Z?

Which can be logically described as `(X_exists Or Y_exists) And Z_exists`

Or in a LINQ-style:

```
Dim retValue As Boolean = 
   (
    userRoles.Any(Function(a) a.Name.Equals("x", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
    Or 
    userRoles.Any(Function(a) a.Name.Equals("y", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
   )
   And 
   userRoles.Any(Function(a) a.Name.Equals("z", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

I took some liberties with the newline placement for clarity's sake.

Comment: logical description will be X_exists Or (Y_exists And Z_exists) that means if x exists then i dont want to check if z exists but if x does not exist and y exists then do check if z also exists

Comment: Change the brackets as required. The main point of my answer was to show you that you can substitute any check you need to do by using the `.Any()` method. What criteria you need to verify is part of the business logic, and I don't have all the information there. Either way, simply phrase your needed verification logically using *and*, *or*, and *brackets*; then substitute where needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are after a one liner, This will help

```
Dim retValue As Boolean =  New String() {"y", "z"}.All(Function(v) userRoles.Contains(v)) OrElse userRoles.Contains("x")
```